# FSharp.Data build error (dotnet build failed with code 134)

Tags: f#, build-error, f#-data

I'm trying to build the FSharp.Data.dll on manjaro KDE linux

after some minor error do to type inference at line 217 in build.fsx got this error.

First of all if FAKE is deprecated shouldn't that been fixed?
Second I can see that the error code 134 is something to do with stackoverflow.

sudo ./build.sh All
advarsel: libunwind-1.3.1-2 er opdateret - springer over
løser afhængigheder...
kigger efter konflikter mellem pakker...

Pakker (1) libunwind-1.3.1-2

Samlet installationsstørrelse:  0,26 MiB
Netto opgraderingsstørrelse:   0,00 MiB

:: Fortsæt med installation? [J/n] n (got it already)
Paket version 6.0.0-alpha050
The last restore is still up to date. Nothing left to do.
Performance:

- Runtime: 56 milliseconds
  This runner is now obsolete with FAKE 5, please upgrade to the new .Net Core runner. See https://fake.build/fake-migrate-to-fake-5.html
  To remove this warning you can append the '--removeLegacyFakeWarning' argument or set the 'FAKE_NO_LEGACY_WARNING' environment variable to 'true'
  Starting task 'DotNet:version': running dotnet --version
  /usr/bin/mono --version
  /usr/bin/dotnet    --version
  3.1.108 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version [2.1.403] from [/home/kam/Skrivebord/Learn FSharp/FSharp.Data/global.json] was not found
  Install the [2.1.403] .NET Core SDK or update [/home/kam/Skrivebord/Learn FSharp/FSharp.Data/global.json] with an installed .NET Core SDK:
  Finished (Failed) 'DotNet:version' in 00:00:00.0482152
  Desired .NET SDK version = 2.1.403
  DotNetCli.isInstalled() = false
  *** The .NET SDK version '2.1.403' will be installed (no other version was found by FAKE helpers)
  Starting task 'DotNet:version': running dotnet --version
  /usr/bin/dotnet    --version
  A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version [2.1.403] from [/home/../FSharp.Data/global.json] was not found
  3.1.108 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  Install the [2.1.403] .NET Core SDK or update [/home/../FSharp.Data/global.json] with an installed .NET Core SDK:
  Finished (Failed) 'DotNet:version' in 00:00:00.0028985
  Retrieving version failed, assuming because it doesn't match global.json, error was: dotnet --version failed with code 145                                (??? what)
  Starting task 'DotNet:version': running dotnet --version
  /root/.dotnet/dotnet    --version
  2.1.403
  Finished (Success) 'DotNet:version' in 00:00:00.0614412
  run All
  Building project with version: LocalBuild
  Shortened DependencyGraph for Target All:
  <== All
  <== NuGet
  <== Build
  <== AssemblyInfo
  <== Clean
  <== BuildTests
  <== RunTests

The running order is:
Group - 1

- Clean
  Group - 2
- AssemblyInfo
  Group - 3
- Build
  Group - 4
- NuGet
- BuildTests
  Group - 5
- RunTests
  Group - 6
- All
  Starting target 'Clean'
  Finished (Success) 'Clean' in 00:00:00.2714356
  Starting target 'AssemblyInfo'
  Finished (Success) 'AssemblyInfo' in 00:00:00.0147815
  Starting target 'Build'
  Starting task 'DotNet:build': src/FSharp.Data.DesignTime/FSharp.Data.DesignTime.fsproj
  /root/.dotnet/dotnet  build /v:n /p:SourceLinkCreate=true src/FSharp.Data.DesignTime/FSharp.Data.DesignTime.fsproj --configuration Release
  No usable version of the libssl was found
  Finished (Failed) 'DotNet:build' in 00:00:00.3258991
  Finished (Failed) 'Build' in 00:00:00.3269533

---

### Build Time Report

Target         Duration

---

Clean          00:00:00.2701083

AssemblyInfo   00:00:00.0147495

Build          00:00:00.3267785   (dotnet build failed with code 134)

NuGet          00:00:00           (skipped)

BuildTests     00:00:00           (skipped)

RunTests       00:00:00           (skipped)

All            00:00:00           (skipped)

Total:         00:00:00.6523077

### Status:        Failure

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> Fake.Core.BuildFailedException: Target 'Build' failed. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (dotnet build failed with code 134) ---> System.Exception: dotnet build failed with code 134
at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule+PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1645[TResult].Invoke (System.String message) [0x00000] in <5b5a6cc1904cf4daa7450383c16c5a5b>:0
at Fake.DotNet.DotNet.build (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] setParams, System.String project) [0x00068] in <5b5f575eccf1c534a74503835e575f5b>:0  at FSI_0005.Build+clo@165-16.Invoke (System.String proj) [0x00005] in <4e926cae0a3648abb70fe31f81695eff>:0  at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Iterate[T] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] action, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x0002c] in <5b5a6cc1904cf4daa7450383c16c5a5b>:0  at FSI_0005.Build+clo@163-15.Invoke (Fake.Core.TargetParameter _arg1) [0x0000a] in <4e926cae0a3648abb70fe31f81695eff>:0  at Fake.Core.TargetModule.runSimpleInternal (Fake.Core.TargetContext context, Fake.Core.Target target) [0x0002b] in <5b5f575eccf1c534a74503835e575f5b>:0  --- End of inner exception stack trace --- --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Fake.Core.TargetModule.runInternal (System.Boolean singleTarget, System.Int32 parallelJobs, System.String targetName, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] args) [0x002fa] in <5b5f575eccf1c534a74503835e575f5b>:0
at Fake.Core.TargetModule.runWithDefault$cont@795-1 (System.Boolean allowArgs, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] fDefault, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpMap`2[TKey,TValue] results, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar) [0x001a5] in <5b5f575eccf1c534a74503835e575f5b>:0
at <StartupCode$FSI_0005>.$FSI_0005_Build$fsx.main@ () [0x00610] in <4e926cae0a3648abb70fe31f81695eff>:0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <671ef0784b04474c83bb500a849492f2>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00083] in <671ef0784b04474c83bb500a849492f2>:0
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in <671ef0784b04474c83bb500a849492f2>:0
at Fake.FSIHelper+runScriptCached@360.Invoke (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar0) [0x00082] in <5b5f575eccf1c534a74503835e575f5b>:0
/home/kam/Skrivebord/Learn FSharp/FSharp.Data/build.fsx(205,10): warning FS0044: This construct is deprecated. This API is obsolete. There is no alternative in FAKE 5 yet. You can help by porting this module.
/home/kam/Skrivebord/Learn FSharp/FSharp.Data/build.fsx(205,5): warning FS0044: This construct is deprecated. This API is obsolete. There is no alternative in FAKE 5 yet. You can help by porting this module.
Fake.Core.BuildFailedException: Target 'Build' failed. ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (dotnet build failed with code 134) ---> System.Exception: dotnet build failed with code 134
at Microsoft.FSharp.Core.PrintfModule+PrintFormatToStringThenFail@1645[TResult].Invoke (System.String message) [0x00000] in <5b5a6cc1904cf4daa7450383c16c5a5b>:0
at Fake.DotNet.DotNet.build (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] setParams, System.String project) [0x00068] in <5b5f575eccf1c534a74503835e575f5b>:0  at FSI_0005.Build+clo@165-16.Invoke (System.String proj) [0x00005] in <4e926cae0a3648abb70fe31f81695eff>:0  at Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.SeqModule.Iterate[T] (Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] action, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x0002c] in <5b5a6cc1904cf4daa7450383c16c5a5b>:0  at FSI_0005.Build+clo@163-15.Invoke (Fake.Core.TargetParameter _arg1) [0x0000a] in <4e926cae0a3648abb70fe31f81695eff>:0  at Fake.Core.TargetModule.runSimpleInternal (Fake.Core.TargetContext context, Fake.Core.Target target) [0x0002b] in <5b5f575eccf1c534a74503835e575f5b>:0  --- End of inner exception stack trace --- --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Fake.Core.TargetModule.runInternal (System.Boolean singleTarget, System.Int32 parallelJobs, System.String targetName, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[T] args) [0x002fa] in <5b5f575eccf1c534a74503835e575f5b>:0
at Fake.Core.TargetModule.runWithDefault$cont@795-1 (System.Boolean allowArgs, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.FSharpFunc`2[T,TResult] fDefault, Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpMap`2[TKey,TValue] results, Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Unit unitVar) [0x001a5] in <5b5f575eccf1c534a74503835e575f5b>:0
at <StartupCode$FSI_0005>.$FSI_0005_Build$fsx.main@ () [0x00610] in <4e926cae0a3648abb70fe31f81695eff>:0
at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo,object,object[],System.Exception&)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x0006a] in <671ef0784b04474c83bb500a849492f2>:0
Stopped due to error

Answer (score 0):

Fix this problem before you proceed:

```sh
 A compatible installed .NET Core SDK for global.json version [2.1.403] from [/home/kam/Skrivebord/Learn FSharp/FSharp.Data/global.json] was not found Install the [2.1.403] .NET Core SDK or update [/home/kam/Skrivebord/Learn FSharp/FSharp.Data/global.json] with an installed .NET Core SDK:
```

The mentioned global.json refers to a sdk version fake/dotnet don't think you have installed.